# Do I need to code Windows 8 RT and Windows Phone 8 hybrid app seperatly?

Tags: windows, cordova, windows-phone-8

I am developing windows 8 RT app using phonegap technology but now my client wants app support for WP8, IOS and Andriod. So my question is that Do I need to change recode for other platform or I can just export it for other platforms?

build.phonegap.com service doesn't support windows 8 RT build.

I am just confused in Windows 8RT and WP8 phonegap technology support.

**Update:**

Actually I am coding it for Windows 8 RT using cordova. My question was Can I use same code for IOS, Android and Windows Phone 8?

Answer (score 0):

Windows Phone RT, are the new 8.1 apps, based on new tools and libraries.
They share more common feature with Windows 8.1 RT apps, than its predecessor (Windows Phone 8 Silverlight) and provide new APIs. There is still support for Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight apps, although they are different from Windows Phone 8.1 RT.

Your might want to edit your description as it is not very clear, you say you develop a Windows 8 RT app (thats a Windows 8.x app, not a Phone app), then on the next line you mention 
that build.phonegap.com service doesn't support windows 8 RT build.

Do you develop for the tablet or for the phone?